# How to get relative path of a image file

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc

I need to get relative path of a certain image(add.png) file in my eclipse project.
Print screen has been attached.

[image]

My java class path is the src/main/java/com/abc/controller/myClass.java

Comment: where you want to access the image? 1. client 2. server side

Answer (score 1):

Try using the classloader object.

```
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
```

This will let you access files on the classpath. Look at the `getResource` method that returns a `URL`.

I notice in your screenshot that eclipse is not categorizing "src/main/webapp" under "Java Resources". I think this means eclipse is not putting that webapp folder in your classpath. You may need to configure the eclipse build path. In brief, right-click on the project, click properties, click "build path" on the left, select the "source" tab, and add "src/main/webapp".

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your classpath entries in  your eclipse. As it seems to be a maven project, so most likely your webapp directory should be part of classpath. And if that is the case, then relative url for your file will start from directory images,like this:

```
images/add.png
```

Comment: I tried  ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
      System.out.println(loader.getResource("images/signature.png"));       But it gets null.

Answer (score 0):

The relative path starts from `/`.

If you are accessing the image in JSP file then you can try with core tag library.

for example:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<c:url value="/images/add.png"/>
```

---

If you want to access the image file at server side then put the file under `resources` folder that goes directly to classpath.

You can try with Spring [`ClassPathResource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.8/api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html) to read the resources from classpath that are stored directly under `resources` folder.

For example:

```
    try (InputStream in = new ClassPathResource("/images/add.png").getInputStream())
    {
        ...
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        ....
    }
```